# Adding user to ownership in addition to another user

Tags: linux, apache, ssh, permissions, centos

I had some problems with permissions, the programmers of my website wanted me to add the admin user to the apache group and then set some permissions. My knowledge of Linux is quite limited, so I found the following online:

```
chown -R apache:apache /path/to/webserver/www 
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

This worked perfectly, and all was well for few days (BTW, I used "apache" instead of www-data since I'm on CentOS).
Now, they're saying they can't upload files to that folder since it is owned by apache user, while they want it to be owned by apache AND admin user.

How do I add 'admin' to ownership as well in addition to 'apache'?

Thanks

Comment: You should really make sure you separate you web app from the data, e.g. in `/var/web-data/` and `/var/web-app/` or something like that. That will also make it much easier to set the rights as needed. What you are doing is a security incident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Create a group and add both the users in that group.
Then the set the permission for the entire group.

1. Create a group
   `groupadd <groupname>`
2. Add both the users, admin and apache to this group.

`usermod -a -G <groupname> admin`

`usermod -a -G <groupname> apache`

3. Change the group and let apache be the owner

`chown -R apache:<groupname> /path/to/webserver/www`

4. Assign permission to the group (admin and apache)

`chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www`